# "what country" vs. "which country"

Tags: word-usage

A classmate and I were practicing speaking where he used a saying "the early bird catches the worm", I did hear this idiom though I didn't know where it originated, so I asked

> Do you know **what country** it originates from?

Is this sentence clear and natural?

Should have I said it like this?

> Do you know **which country** it originates from?

Comment: Either of them would be improved by inserting _from_ either after _originates_ or before _what_.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks for your reminder. I’ve just updated it.

Comment: What country in the world? Which country, Spain or Japan?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3414/) for more detail.

Those both sound natural to me if the answer could be any country. However, if you have narrowed down the set of possible answers, I would be more inclined to say “which” sounds more natural. It also depends on the phrasing of your question.

Usage of either word will be understood by a native English speaker, and using the ‘wrong’ one will only sound a little awkward.

Comment: Yeah, native speakers use both. "Which" is a little more formal/proper.